# C# running foreign exe inside windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, exe

I'm trying to run discord.exe inside a windows form but im getting this error. Can someone help me, thanks. Here is the error message: Error message in English ("The system cannot find the file specified")

[image]

These are my codes:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr child, IntPtr newParent);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int Iparam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);
    private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 274;
    private const int SC_MAXIMIZE = 61488;


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string anan = "discord.exe";
        Process calistir = Process.Start(anan);
        while (calistir.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero || !IsWindowVisible(calistir.MainWindowHandle))
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            calistir.Refresh();
        }

        SetParent(calistir.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);
        SendMessage(calistir.MainWindowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0);

    }
```

Comment: I assume the message says: *The system cannot find the file specified* (btw, you should provide the exception details as text, in English). Use the full path of the executable -- You, usually, use `[Process].WaitForInputIdle()` to wait for the process' interface to show up (in case of a windowed Process). So, remove that `while` loop -- There's no guarantee that `SetParent` will produce the desired result anyway.

Comment: Yeah you are right. It says "The system cannot find the file specified" Thanks btw, I'll edit the post for this message. But I can't use the full path of the executable file because the location can be change for other people. It will be a launcher. @Jimi

Comment: You have to use the full path, in a way or another. So, look for the executable path in the Registry.

Comment: Yeah, I did, i tried this one : "C:\Users\Hasancan\AppData\Local\Discord\app-0.0.305\discord.exe"

Comment: *I tried this one*? Where does that string come from? From a [Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry) lookup? *Look for the executable path in the Registry* of course implies *using dev tools*, not your eyes :) (you have to know where the application stores its path in the registry and retrieve this path at run-time)

Comment: Honestly, I don't know do that i mean the registry thing. I searched some topics for that but, I guess, I don't understand registry thing :D Could you send me a tutorial for this? https://prnt.sc/qj9xib

Comment: I've already done that. See the Registry link in my previous comment.

Comment: Still trying to do that :D

Answer (score -1):

if you wanna run the software, first you have to give the path of the file. I changed the code but you have to change it according to the information on your computer. Then it will work.

You can see the screenshot here: Discord App => Properties
https://i.hizliresim.com/1p5ZYG.jpg

```
string anan = @"C:\Users\YouPC\AppData\Local\Discord\Discord.exe";
Process calistir = Process.Start(anan);
while (calistir.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero || 
    !IsWindowVisible(calistir.MainWindowHandle))
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
    calistir.Refresh();
}

SetParent(calistir.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);
SendMessage(calistir.MainWindowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks Bayram, I tried this one but i got the same error. Also there is a thing you should check it: https://i.hizliresim.com/EOoBJn.png